# How to Make A SQL Data Source Delete Statement Delete Selected Item

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, datasource

I am trying to delete the selected item on a grid view from a sql server database.
I have my DataKeyNames set and a sql data source with the grid view pointing to it. I have a delete command:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM cartsigns WHERE SignName = @SignName"
```

And A select command:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM cartsigns WHERE ((ipaddress = @ipaddress) AND (ipaddress = @ipaddress2))"
```

I then have my delete paramerter:

```
    <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter 
            ControlID="GridView1" 
            Name="SignName" 
            PropertyName="SelectedDataKey" />
    </DeleteParameters>
```

But when I select a item and push the delete button it does not delete.
Thanks for your help.

p.s. The purpose for this is a shopping cart and I want to be able to delete items in my cart.

Please Please Help

Comment: what is the markup for the grid? did you set the datakeys?

Comment: yes, check out my answer to my questian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem! I needed to change my property name on my delete paramerters to `SelectedValue`.

I also had forgot to set my key on my database. And I accidently changed my sort expressions, but after I got those fixed it started working.